# How can I calculate daily active users for salesforce logins?

Tags: login, data-export, login-history

We are exporting data from salesforce into our data warehouse, and I need to be able to calculate

- daily active users
- daily sessions

in order to be able to combine it with metrics calculated from other data sources, but I can't figure out how to do this. The user table doesn't maintain a history of logins, just the most recent login. The only relevant documentation I can find about this discusses how to calculate this within salesforce reporting, but that doesn't help me (unless there is a way to export custom reports via the API).

Can anyone help me? Alternatively, I haven't seen much discussion here about exporting data from salesforce to a data warehouse, so I wonder if this is the wrong stack exchange for these questions?

Comment: https://help.salesforce.com/s/articleView?id=000328233&type=1

Answer (score 1):

The object you probably want is [LoginHistory](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.object_reference.meta/object_reference/sforce_api_objects_loginhistory.htm). This gives you every login attempt by every user in your org. Note, it includes attempts, so you would need to filter by successful logins.